# Blank Space in every row of table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello i have a table with rows

and i was doing a simple

```
select from table where column ='string'
```

and it gives me back no result, but when i use:

```
select from table where column ='%string%'
```

it gives me the row that exist in my table,

then i did a `select * from table` and noticed that there is a blank space before my rows:

[Image of my SQL result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ6kH.png)
[image]

If you look closely theres a space at the beginning of the second row, and only in the first row theres no blank space.

so i thought it was a simple white space at the beggining but when i tried using this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(MATERIAL)) FROM table
```

nothing happened.

then i tried to copy the result of my

```
select * from table
```

to Excel and noticed this:

[Excel paste from SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ADac.png)
[image]

my 2nd row got splitted in 2 rows right at the start of the column 'material', so the thing i thught it was a blank space its something like a jump line.

i have never had this problem before or seen this before.

Comment: `SELECT ASCII(LEFT(material, 1)) FROM table` - it will probably say `9`

Comment: Sounds like the character isn't a space, but something else. What does `ASCII(LEFT(YourColumn,1))` return?

Comment: 49 on the first row and 10 on every other row

Comment: `ASCII(10)` is a line break. Try `UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn = REPLACE(YourColumn,CHAR(10),'');` and run your query again.

Comment: according to an ASCII table the 10 is 'New Line', do you know how to remove this?

Comment: See my above comment.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu this solved my Issue, but is tehre any way i can know where this character came from?

Comment: From whomever, or whatever, inserted the data.

Comment: is there any way to prevent people to insert anything that is not a character or number in to my table?

Comment: Fix the program that does the insert, or put a trigger on the table to strip off the bad character, or throw an error if the data starts with an ascii 10. I think i've worked out how the data came to be this way, including why one of the records is correct. see my edited answer

Comment: thanks for this answer you explained everything really well.

Comment: *"is there any way to prevent people to insert anything that is not a character or number in to my table"* A line break is a character (with the ASCII code 10). If you only want specific characters, then yes, you could implement something. For example, you might only allow the characters A-z, 0-9 and a whitespace. Of course, that would mean the "number" (string) `'1.0'` is not valid.

Comment: Thanks Larnu you were really helpful too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Larnu has commented how to remove all the linebreaks from the data. Here are some other things that could also work, and slightly differently depending on the effect you want:

```
--trim everything that is not a number or letter off the left hand side only
UPDATE table SET material = SUBSTRING(material, PATINDEX(material, '[0-9a-z]', 99999)

--convert all linebreaks to spaces and trim off the left and right spaces
UPDATE table SET material = RTRIM(LTRIM(REPLACE(material, CHAR(10), ' ')))
```

Larnu's SQL isn't wrong, it'll just remove every line break anywhere, which may cause more formatting disruption than is wanted. I'd be tempted to replace all the linebreaks with spaces, as two words that are separated by a line break would remain separated by a space rather than become one word if the space was removed

```
some
word

-> some word (if you replace linebreak with space)
-> someword (if you replace linebreak with nothing)
```

If all you want is to remove linebreaks from the left side of the field, the patindex method will search the field for the first occurrence of a numbe rof a letter, and return the index, then substring will cut everything from that index for a length of 99999 (use a bigger number if your field is longer). This has the effect of removing only linebreaks at the start of the field

As to how it happened, whoever inserted the data, or the data import program, made some mistakes when it was cutting up the data. Perhaps it was a Windows style text file, whose line endings are CR LF (ascci 13 followed by 10), and the program that did the import decided to cut the file up based on the 13 only, leaving behind the 10 to become "part of" the material field:

```
this,is,my,data1<13><10>this,is,my,data2<13><10>

//now lets cut it up into 2 records, based on using <13> only to denote the end of line:

record 1= this,is,my,data1
record 2= <10>this,is,my,data2
```

The program just sees a stream of bytes, it is we humans that interpret "lines". If the program treats 13 as the separator, then all the 10s get left behind as part of the data that gets inserted. The very first record in the file won't have  13/10 (crlf) before it because it's the first line, so one of your rows (the one with ascii (49)) won't suffer this problem

You could "cure" the bad data with a trigger upon insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_bad_data
ON yourtable  
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO yourtable(somecolumn,othercolumn,material)
      SELECT foo,
             bar,
             LTRIM(REPLACE(material, CHAR(10), ' '))
      FROM   Inserted
  END
```

Or you could program the db to reject bad rows and fix the tool that is inserting the bad data:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD CONSTRAINT prevent_bad_material 
CHECK material LIKE '[0-9a-z]%';  --check it starts with a number or letter
```

Edit: though having seen your updated question with screenshots, the material column really should be a number, not a varchar type, then this wouldn't happen

Comment: added some info, but thats kinda a separate question; if this isn't sufficient, ask another

Comment: thanks this is very detailed, and the material collumn also has non numbers hence the varchar instead of number.